# How to modify devstack after basic deployment

Tags: openstack, devstack

I have deployed a basic openstack using devstack. now I want to install additional component like designate or magnum. What is the way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I would try the [Magnum installation guide](https://docs.openstack.org/magnum/latest/install). It gives you two options: Install using apt/yum/zypper packages, or install [using pip](https://docs.openstack.org/magnum/latest/install/install-guide-from-source.html).

You need to ensure you install the version that matches your Devstack version. E.g. if your Devstack is Ussuri, use [Ussuri instructions](https://docs.openstack.org/magnum/ussuri/install/).

Another possibility might be [amending local.conf](https://opendev.org/openstack/magnum/src/branch/master/devstack) and rerun stack.sh. I am not sure if this breaks already installed software, though.

The safest solution is to add the `enable_plugin` directives for Magnum to local.conf before you deploy the cloud.

Comment: your mentioned first option is manual, if there is no other option , then I will try . I have tried second option(rerun stack.sh), and it breaks already installed components.